# JavaScript - Textbox - Removing characters from a string/textbox depending on the location of the cursor/highlight

Tags: javascript, string, input

So I am creating a password meter just for practise. I have a textbox where the user will enter their password to be checked. It updates automatically as you type so it's not a case of typing the password and pressing a button.

Which leads me to my problem. If the user presses the backspace button, it slices a character from the end of the string, the problem is, if the cursor is moved to say, the middle of the password and a character is removed, it still only slices a character from the END not the position of the cursor. The same occurs if highlighting and deleting a portion or all of the password, it only removes the end character.

Now I can obviously see where the problem is in the code, as it's currently just using pass.slice(0,-1) which will of course remove the last character.

My question is...is there a function or a technique I can use so that I am able to remove characters depending on the location of the cursor/if the user highlights and deletes.

I guess some psuedo code would be..

```
if (keycode == 8) {
  pass.slice(0,cursorposition -1);
}
```

Here is the relevant code that I am currently using.

```
passDOM.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) { 
    strengthInit(e); //pass the event to the initiation class
});

function strengthInit(eKey) {

     if (eKey.keyCode == 8) { //user pressed the backspace button
            if (pass.length == 1) { //check to see if user deleted the password
                pass = "";
                document.getElementById("resultContainer").remove(); //remove the results 
            } else {
                pass = pass.slice(0, -1); //remove a character
                finalScore = PasswordSecurity(pass); //run through the checker
            }
    } else if (eKey.keyCode == 46 ) {  //Delete key was pressed  
    //TODO: determine the lcoation of the cursor and delete one before or after

   } else { //user has entered a new character, append to the end of the string
       pass += eKey.key
       finalScore = PasswordSecurity(pass); //run through the checker
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I got it working using selectionStart and selectionEnd.

I don't know if there is a more efficient way to do this.

```
if (passDOM.selectionStart == passDOM.selectionEnd) { //only deleting one character
        pass = pass.replace(pass[passDOM.selectionEnd -1], "");
} else { //deleting a selection
        var result = pass.substring(passDOM.selectionStart, passDOM.selectionEnd);
        pass = pass.replace(result,"");
        finalScore = PasswordSecurity(pass);
}
```